# order of gridview itmes to open Activity1 and Activity2

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, gridview

I am working on a project,where i have 4 activities, main activity have `Griview` I want to open `Activity` 1  by clicking item 1 and open `Activity` 2 by clicking item 2
I want to help complete this work.

CustomAdapter.java:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_gridlayout, null);
    holder.os_text =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.os_texts);
    holder.os_img =(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.os_images);

    holder.os_text.setText(result[position]);
    holder.os_img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return rowView;
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GridView gridview;

public static String[] osNameList = {
        "Android",
        "Android",
        "Android",
        "Android",
        "Android",
        "Android",
        "Android",
        "Android",
};
public static int[] osImages = {
        R.mipmap.android,
        R.mipmap.ios,
        R.mipmap.linux,
        R.mipmap.macos,
        R.mipmap.msdos,
        R.mipmap.symbian,
        R.mipmap.windows10,
        R.mipmap.winxp,};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.customgrid);
    gridview.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, osNameList, osImages));
}
```

}

Comment: what is the problen you are facing?

Comment: you want to open "Activity8" while click on item 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Implement On Item click listener

```
     gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

            switch(position)
            {
            case 1:
    //Intent to open Avtivity 2
Intent in2 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Activity2);
startActivity(in2);
            break;

            case 2:
    //Intent to open Avtivity 1
Intent in1 = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Activity1);
startActivity(in1);
                break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(GinfyActivity.this, "Wrong Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yas I want to open another activity a wail I click item a and open activity b wail click item b

Comment: For that only I posted that Code. Check edited code now

Comment: plez .. how can i translate  osNameList in Gridview  to anther language (code plez )

Comment: Refer this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html